# Titanium Appcelerator PUT method not working

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I have a RESTful web service and a client written on Titanium Mobile.

What's weird is that all of the HTTP verbs, POST, GET and DELETE are working with an exception for PUT method. Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u share the code or error wot u getting while requesting to the server

Comment: It looks like they did not fully implement it yet. This question has also been bothering me, and this solution seems just fine. http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/123042/only-get-and-post-methods-in-httpclient--no-put-or-delete

Comment: Hi guys, is this fixed in SDK 6.3.0. GA ?